# Short jQuery works, everything else goes blank

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show "Test" depending on the screen size:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function( $ ){
if($(window).width() >= 960){
document.write('Test');
}
});
</script>
```

Due to a jQuery-conflict, I had to put the script within "jQuery(funcion..."

So the script works. However, the entire site loads normally, then goes blank once the script is executed, with only "Test" showing on screen. Does anyone now why?

Comment: Because of `document.write('Test');`. You are replacing your entire document with text `Test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once document ready fires, if you use [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) again, the document will get rewritten, if you want to append a text you can use append()

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling
>   document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls
>   document.open [which will clear the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open#Notes).

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
if($(window).width() >= 960){
$('body').append('test')
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can't use document.write once the document has completed loading. If you do, the browser will open a new document that replaces the current.

[JavaScript Document.Write Replaces All Body Content When Using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360076/javascript-document-write-replaces-all-body-content-when-using-ajax)