# How to create HTML table based on JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to create `HTML` table based on `JSON`  input. here is my `JSON` sample input.

```
[
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "rooter",
    "Password": "12345",
    "Country": "UK",
    "Email": "sac@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 2,
    "UserName": "binu",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "Binu@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 3,
    "UserName": "cal",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "cal@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 4,
    "UserName": "nera",
    "Password": "1234",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "nera@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

Expected result:

[image]

I need to do this while the web page is loading.

Comment: Is there any specific thing you need assistance with? Can you please share with us any attempts you have made? It'll be a lot easier to help if we see which direction you have chosen to take.

Comment: So loop over and build a table. Do you know how to loop over the array? Do you know how to build a string?

Comment: I think if you dont know secific keys you have to do this using recursion

Comment: @MaciejKozieja - no need for recursion here. `Object.keys()` will get you all of the keys for an object - you can then iterate over them just like a normal array.

Comment: @epascarello no i don't know friend :( can you provide me some sample code to do this

Comment: @Lix how can i do this,can you help me to? i am new to this :(

Comment: @Rooter - if you don't know how to loop over an array or build a string I think you might have some additional work to do before attempting to solve this problem. We're talking about some of the first thing one learns when starting to program.

Comment: @lix if you have obejct inside obejct inside object this loop would be over complicated

Comment: @MaciejKozieja - no one mentioned nested objects :) I am taking the OPs sample JSON as the example (since it is the only one given)

Comment: It is JavaScript basics:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238173/javascript-loop-through-json-array learn the basics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have done your job, as you don't know. Please follow my code below and do changes what you needed in your application. But you should include **library** files hosted by your server for faster results::

**FULL CODE**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "rooter",
    "Password": "12345",
    "Country": "UK",
    "Email": "sac@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 2,
    "UserName": "binu",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "Binu@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 3,
    "UserName": "cal",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "cal@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 4,
    "UserName": "nera",
    "Password": "1234",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "nera@gmail.com"
  }
];
$(document).ready(function () {
    var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
    html += '<tr>';
    var flag = 0;
    $.each(data[0], function(index, value){
        html += '<th>'+index+'</th>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';
     $.each(data, function(index, value){
         html += '<tr>';
        $.each(value, function(index2, value2){
            html += '<td>'+value2+'</td>';
        });
        html += '<tr>';
     });
     html += '</table>';
     $('body').html(html);
});
</script>
```

AND it will look like image below:

[image]

Comment: You've hard coded the columns of the table. The question was to build a table according to the provided JSON object. Any change to that object will break your code.

Comment: In addition you have forgotten to mention a dependency you have used. `table-striped` is from `bootstrap` if I'm not mistaken..

Comment: Yes i am sending please wait.

Comment: @Rooter Please follow my updated answer

Comment: @Lix Ahh, sorry i was in a hurry. Now i think negative is required.

Comment: @rooter if it worked for you please accept the answer for helping others

Comment: What mail. I just answeresd your question

Comment: @RanaGhosh ok dude,sorry logged with my mobile,so i didn't saw answer properly , thanks , i'll check and accept it

Comment: @RanaGhosh hey friend, suppose JSON is generate by php, so then how to give a json input as a parameter to this function

Comment: @RanaGhosh your code working fine ,but i have some two problem. problem 1: when i use this in php,when i executed your code with some other things,only  this table showing and not other content displaying(ex: images), problem 2: how i can send json as parameter to this function

Answer (score 9):

Go through all elements from your JSON array and save all different keys to javascript array or similar.

Then, using all these keys create table and table header row with columns.

Then, go through all JSON objects and print one row for each object.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "rooter",
    "Password": "12345",
    "Country": "UK",
    "Email": "sac@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 2,
    "UserName": "binu",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "Binu@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 3,
    "UserName": "cal",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "cal@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 4,
    "UserName": "nera",
    "Password": "1234",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "nera@gmail.com"
  }
];

var keys = [];

document.write("<table border==\"1\"><tr>");
for (key in data[0]) {
 document.write('<td>' + key + '</td>');
}
document.write("</tr>");
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 document.write('<tr>');
 for (key in data[i]) {
   document.write('<td>' + data[i][key] + '</td>');
  }
 document.write('</tr>');
}
document.write("</table>");
```

Comment: Thanks tilz0R, can you provide me some sample code,please :(

Comment: I've updated my post.
Downwoter, do we have a reason for downvote?

Comment: Need more proof? http://screencloud.net/v/io3lk Don't know where you heard that info. Still don't know why downvotes.

Comment: @tilz0R - seems like i spoke too soon! appologies for the confusion

Comment: Ok whatever..I showed him basic principle. You can (I don't care much) save everything into one variable and then call jquery to set as HTML.

Comment: @tilz0R - I think this is what confused me a bit - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2360112/558021. `document.write` **will** replace the contents if the page has already loaded.

Comment: I never personally used document.write but here AND on W3Schools it works the same.

Comment: @tilz0R - when using a sandboxed code preview tool there is a posibility that results will vary. jsfiddle.net doesn't even allow the use of `document.write` in their service. (I also never use `document.write`.)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would have done

```js
var object = [
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "rooter",
    "Password": "12345",
    "Country": "UK",
    "Email": "sac@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 2,
    "UserName": "binu",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "Binu@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 3,
    "UserName": "cal",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "cal@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 4,
    "UserName": "nera",
    "Password": "1234",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "nera@gmail.com"
  }
];


function createTable(){
 $('#content').append('<table id="jsonTable"><thead><tr></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>');
 
  $.each(Object.keys(object[0]), function(index, key){
    $('#jsonTable thead tr').append('<th>' + key + '</th>');
  }); 
  $.each(object, function(index, jsonObject){     
    if(Object.keys(jsonObject).length > 0){
      var tableRow = '<tr>';
      $.each(Object.keys(jsonObject), function(i, key){
         tableRow += '<td>' + jsonObject[key] + '</td>';
      });
      tableRow += "</tr>";
      $('#jsonTable tbody').append(tableRow);
    }
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  createTable();
});
```

```css
tr:nth-child(even) td {background: #f2f2f2}

table{
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th{
 border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}
table thead{
 background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: You are creating the table header dynamically according to the provided JSON, but then when populating the table you are still using hard coded keys - this code will break if the JSON changes at all (adding an extra key)

Comment: @Lix I just modified my code so it would work if you added a new key

Answer (score -2):

```
var data = jsonObject;
var table = document.createElement("table");
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var thUserID = document.createElement("th");
var thUserName = document.createElement("th");
var thPassword = document.createElement("th");
var thCountry = document.createElement("th");
var thEmail = document.createElement("th");
thUserID.innerText = "userID";
thUserName.innerText = "userName";
thPassword.innerText = "password";
thCountry.innerText = "country";
thEmail.innerText = "email";
tr.appendChild(thUserID);
tr.appendChild(thUserName);
tr.appendChild(thPassword);
tr.appendChild(thCountry);
tr.appendChild(thEmail);    
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var userID = data[i].UserID;
    var userName = data[i].UserName;
    var password = data[i].Password;
    var country = data[i].Country;
    var email = data[i].Email;
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var tdUserID = document.createElement("td");
    tdUserID.innerText = userID;
    var tdUserName = document.createElement("td");
    tdUserName.innerText = userName;
    var tdPassword = document.createElement("td");
    tdPassword.innerText = password;
    var tdCountry = document.createElement("td");
    tdCountry.innerText = country;
    var tdEmail = document.createElement("td");
    tdEmail.innerText = email;
    tr.appendChild(tdUserID);
    tr.appendChild(tdUserName);
    tr.appendChild(tdPassword);
    tr.appendChild(tdCountry);
    tr.appendChild(tdEmail);
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: I see that you are just trying to help out - but this solution is too hard coded - the moment the JSON data changes (adding an extra key), this code will break.

Comment: The more I use StackOverflow the less I like it. You asked a specific question you got a specific answer. You could use a for(i in data) instead if you'd like.

Comment: Wow, I got a down vote for answering the question exactly but it failed to anticipate that the OP may have wanted something different?