# How to build a dynamic html table from json data using node js?

Tags: json, node.js, express, ejs

There is a small project at nodejs + express + postgres for self-education. By requesting Postgres I get data in json format, then the data on the express tools is rendered to the ejs template. The very question is how do I add this json to a dynamic table in html.

The request to the database looks like this

```
    const pool = new pg.Pool(config);

 router.get('/index', (req, res, next) => {
    pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Can not connect to the DB" + err);
        }
        client.query('SELECT * FROM srt_final WHERE info_init @> \'{"subscriber":"999999"}\' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20', function (err, result) {
             done();
             if (err) {
                 console.log(err);
                 res.status(400).send(err);
             }
             var osaka = result.rows;

                     res.render('index', {  srt: osaka });
        })

    })
 });
```

The data itself looks like this (about 30 values).

```
    [
{"id":11653167,"info_init":
  {"date":"05.07.2018"},
   ....
  {"Time":"10:31:17"}
},
  ....
{"id":11653168,"info_init":
  {:},
    ......
  {:}
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref: [How to create HTML table based on JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558090/how-to-create-html-table-based-on-json)

```
 var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
    html += '<tr>';
    var flag = 0;
    $.each(data[0], function(index, value){
        html += '<th>'+index+'</th>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';
     $.each(data, function(index, value){
         html += '<tr>';
        $.each(value, function(index2, value2){
            html += '<td>'+value2+'</td>';
        });
        html += '<tr>';
     });
     html += '</table>';
     $('body').html(html);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my cases when using this example, I get this result: id info_init info_final state
12293245 [object Object] [object Object] 1
12291387 [object Object] [object Object] 1

Comment: Ref: i created a example  https://embed.plnkr.co/apjw1FF4Qu3yc1B3bSb6/ because your object has some nested data inside the key "info_init"

Answer (score 2):

A little too late maybe, but the solutions I found didn't work quite well. I needed something simpler, not a template engine or a lib. Also, the mentioned npm package, html-tablify, didnt work for me when trying to generate a table from a Mongoose response. Btw, sorry for my bad english.

```
const row = html => `<tr>\n${html}</tr>\n`,
      heading = object => row(Object.keys(object).reduce((html, heading) => (html + `<th>${heading}</th>`), '')),
      datarow = object => row(Object.values(object).reduce((html, value) => (html + `<td>${value}</td>`), ''));
                               
function htmlTable(dataList) {
  return `<table>
            ${heading(dataList[0])}
            ${dataList.reduce((html, object) => (html + datarow(object)), '')}
          </table>`
}

const set = [
  {_id: 1234,
    usuario: 'user1',
    clave: 'pass1' },
  {_id: 12345,
    usuario: 'user2',
    clave: 'asdas' },
  {_id: 12357,
    usuario: 'user3',
    clave: 'asdasd' },
  {_id: 12376,
    usuario: 'user5',
    clave: 'asdasd' }
];

htmlTable(set)
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>_id</th>
    <th>usuario</th>
    <th>clave</th>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
     <td>123</td>
     <td>xD</td>
     <td>asd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>123</td>
     <td>xD</td>
     <td>asd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>123</td>
     <td>xD</td>
     <td>asd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>123</td>
     <td>xD</td>
     <td>asd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How does it works... it is actually pretty simple.
The `row` function wraps some value inside a  tag.
`heading`, on the other side, takes an object and creates the table heading html based on the object's own keys.
`datarow`, takes an object, and genereate all the cells of the row
Both heading and datarow functions returns a row html code by using the row function.
`htmlTable` function receives a list of objects, and just returns the full table's html code.

With a few tweaks, markup formatting, attributes and styles can be easily added.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about NodeJS related question, you can look into html table how to make table in html. Then render dynamic contents by nodejs better is use a view engine like ejs.

Comment: Can you tell me how to bring out the contents of all "info_init".

Comment: info_init means ?

Comment: [
{"id":11653167,"info_init":
  {"date":"05.07.2018"},
   ....
  {"Time":"10:31:17"}
},
  ....
{"id":11653168,"info_init":
  {:},
    ......
  {:}
}
]

Comment: That is, fill the table with content only "info_init"

Comment: Do u use any temple engine

Comment: Yes, i use ejs template

Comment: you passed that result named osaka right then just access into osaka.info_init like this

Answer (score 0):

Use html-tablify

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-tablify

I will create html table from json