# to create the table in HTML ajax response using jQuery based feature column name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a `JSON` response like this:

```
data = [{
    ProteinID: "2334",
    Feature: "GVN",
    Count: 1
  },
  {
    ProteinID: "2334",
    Feature: "LPA",
    Count: 3
  },
  {
    ProteinID: "2334",
    Feature: "EEG",
    Count: 2
  },
  {
    ProteinID: "2334",
    Feature: "VEP",
    Count: 3
  },
  {
    ProteinID: "2334",
    Feature: "AEM",
    Count: 2
  },
  {
    ProteinID: "28731",
    Feature: "GVN",
    Count: 3
  },
  {
    ProteinID: "28731",
    Feature: "LPA",
    Count: 3
  },
  {
    ProteinID: "28731",
    Feature: "VEP",
    Count: 3
  },
  {
    ProteinID: "1234",
    Feature: "VEP",
    Count: 3
  },
   {
    ProteinID: "1234",
    Feature: "MOB",
    Count: 3
  }
]
```

The above data is based the Feature column inner join. I need to create the table in html format like. I retrive the data from database. so the column will be change

Expected output look like

```
ProtienID GVN  LPV  EEG VEP AEM  MOB

2334       1    3   2   3   2    -
28731      3    3   -   3   -    -
1234       -    -   -   3   -    3
```

**note:** column name will be dynamically change

Comment: **So?** what you tried so far? what's the **problem** ? | `I need to create` so create *!*

Comment: i need create the table format look like 2nd code

Comment: i tried to change the data format but i'm not familiar in Jquery so that only i asked

Comment: Take a look [How to create HTML table based on JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558090/how-to-create-html-table-based-on-json)